# Перенаправление браузера

Tags: php

Как перенаправить на главную с каталога уровнем выше? У меня есть зарегистрированный пользователь `$login` и абсолютный путь
`$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` 
`header("location: $root/$login");` - вот так не работает.
`.htaccess` настроен на перенаправление всех запросов на `index.php`

Comment: `var_dump("location: $root/$login");` что выводит.

Comment: location: D:/USR/www/dev1/login

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - это не то, что Вам нужно. Вас интересует  `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос.

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
header("location: $host/$login");
```

Comment: мне перенаправление с высшего каталога нужно, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` отталкивается от этого каталога

Comment: @O.Vykhor , что значит "перенаправление с высшего каталога"? выше главной ничего не может быть. Для перенаправления можно не указывать хост `header("location: /$login");`